Getting length in meters of features in line type layer using PyQGIS
I want to get the length in meters of features with line-type geometry independent of the CRS of the layer and project.
Is there any way to do this?
I used the code below but I'm not sure of the unit of measurement.
p = QgsProject.instance()
layer = p.mapLayersByName('rede')[0]

d = QgsDistanceArea()
d.setEllipsoid('WGS84')

for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    print(d.convertAreaMeasurement(d.measureLength(feat.geometry()), 1)*1000)


You can run:
print(d.lengthUnits())

after you have defined your ellipsoid to see what the units of measurement for length are. Using your example code above, it results in DistanceUnit.Meters.
Ref: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsDistanceArea.html
